# Creating continuously backups with duplicity, uploading them later

Tags: macos, cron, backup, duplicity

I would like to use [duplicity](http://duplicity.nongnu.org) as a second and primarily as a remote backup for my macbook air. I would like to setup the backup as a regularly cronjob. I am traveling a lot so i can not ensure a fast or even an internet connection to my remote backup space at all.

Has anyone an idea how to to create regularly backups and upload them only, if an internet connection is detected, with duplicity?

Answer (score 0):

Try duplicity along with Dropbox. So you copy your data to the local Dropbox directory.
When you have internet connection the dropbox client will sync your backup

Comment: dropbox isn't really useful because there space limitations and the fact that the backup is stored also on my disc that i actually would like to backup. the possibility to configure a temporary directory to permanently store not yet uploaded files would be a great solution. but this is not implemented right now, isn't it?

Comment: Well, I don't know all details that's why can suggest only direction to go, but not the ready recipe. Sure, there is free space limit (2G) if you need to backup more that would be additional cost.
Technically there are no problems, if you backup let's say only $HOME you can put your Dropbox directory in /var or elsewhere.

May be I overcomplicate things and simple shell script can do the job.

Answer (score 0):

I did a cronjobbed duplicity setup with a target being a local copy of iCloud, once there is connectivity the delta is being uploaded automagically.